# Flutter unit testing - unable to pump full widget tree

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, testing, dart

I am just getting started with unit testing in Flutter, and I have hit a bit of a wall. I have a fairly simple app located here:
https://github.com/chuckntaylor/kwjs_flutter_demo

The app is essentially a list view of events where you can tap on one to read more details about the event.

[image: KWJS Flutter App in action]

I have two screens for this: `events_screen.dart` for the list view, and `event_screen.dart` for the details. I have been trying to write my tests in `events_screen_test.dart`

My testing difficulties are with the events screen (the list view). After running `await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: EventsScreen())` I can use `find.text('Events')` for example to find the title in the AppBar, but I cannot find any of the elements that make up the list.

To clarify further. I am using `get_it` as a serviceLocator to get the viewModel for the EventsScreen when it loads. The viewModel is the `ChangeNotifierProvider`, and EventsScreen contains a `Consumer` to update the list. in EventsScreen `initState()`, it calls loadEvents() on the viewModel. After loadEvents() is done, the viewModel calls notifyListeners(), so that EventsScreen can update.

How do I ensure that all these steps occur so that I can properly test if the EventsScreen is rendering properly?

I could be approaching this all wrong, so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved my problem, but perhaps someone can shed some light on this. In the end I executed:

```
await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: EventsScreen(),));
// followed immediately by this second pump without arguments
await tester.pump();
```

At this point,  the Widget tree was complete and I could create Finders as I hoped and could run all my expect statements without issue.

I am not sure exactly why this works though.

Comment: Had a similar problem and wrapping the Screen to test with MaterialApp did the trick. When you expect the source code of `pumpWidget` you see in the docs they write `Calls [runApp] with the given widget` and usually the Widget we pass to runApp() is MultiProvider or MaterialApp.

Answer (score 1):

As you saw calling tester.pump(), after tester.pumpWidget(),  do the job. This works for the following reason: you wrote you are using a Provider, and you run a notifyListener after the data are fetched. Now in a normal application run, you see the widget rebuild since you are using a consumer to that provider. In the test environment, this does not occur if you don't explicitly call a "time advance". You can do it calling await tester.pump() (as you did) and this asks to run a new frame on screen, so now you have your list rendered.